# Android fade right to left

Tags: android, animation, textview

Is it possible to fade a TextView in from right to left? I have a textview that will fade in and out, but I want this fade to start from the right side and move to the left.

Answer (score 2):

What's your looking for is the "TextSwitcher" widget (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html)

You can easily find some tutorials (first picks on google):

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-textswitcher.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html

Comment: I looked into that, it is not what I am looking for. I am looking for a fade animation that will start from the left and fade in to the right.